# Are these requirements correct (variable relations)

Tags: variables, specifications, testcase, requirements

There is this example in a book, reading:

> The
>   system shall allow posting of envelopes where the longest side (l) is
>   longer than or equal to 12 centimeters, but not longer than 75
>   centimeters. The smallest side (w) must be longer than or equal to 1
>   centimeter. The length must be twice the width and must be greater
>   than or equal to 10 centimeters. Measures are always rounded up to the
>   nearest centimeter. We can rewrite this requirement to read:

- length >= 12
- length < 75
- width >= 1
- length – 2 x width >= 10

I do not understand how the last requirement (...l>=10) can coexist with the first requirement (l>=12)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having seen the original text, it is clear that the equation `L - 2 W >= 10` is indeed the author's intent. This constraint makes sense.

Anyway, there are two "bugs" left:

- the textual specification is wrong (should read "The length must be greater than twice the width by 10 centimeters or more" or similar),
- the constraint `L >= 12` is implicit with `W >= 1` and `L - 2 W >= 10`.

An extra typo in the following two tables would tend to confirm that nobody's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In my interpretation there are two differences between the quoted text and the requirements in the bullets:
  - Length must be exactly twice the width so l=2 x w
  - Length must be >= 10

Comment: Well, it reads " twice the width AND must be greater than or equal to 10 "

Comment: I would tend to say that the mistake is on the side of the book. L = 2 x W exactly is too restrictive and makes W >= 1 irrelevant.

Comment: @user144171: Yes but i Would say the AND refers to the length and not to the difference on the length and twice the width.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I would also say that the requirements in the book are not perfect (probably wrong). Since normally you want to express that your envelopes should have a certain amount of rectangularity to allow for easier handling but you wouldn't want exactly rectangular envelopes. Just wanted to point out the difference between text and the bullets

Comment: In that case, it also does not make sense if L must be > 12 (first requirement) and now it must be > 10.

Comment: @user144171: jep your right. Nevertheless I would say the AND refers to the length alone - even though I am no english native speaker. I'll change the wording of my answer :-)